# turtlebot sensors

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I turn off the cliff sensor? or deactivate it for a certain amount of time. I'm driving the robot into an elevator but it can't quite make it in because of the small gap down the shaft... my cmd_vel commands keep getting ignored because the cliff sensors activate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40255/turtlebot-sensors/) by [Rydel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2014/rydel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 600 on 2012-07-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will have to change the turtlebot_node.py code [here](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot/file/fb8354a98ac5/turtlebot_node/nodes/turtlebot_node.py#l492). Right now it sends (0,0) velocity when there is a wheel drop.

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2